# Error while Building Firebreath Solution

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, npapi, firebreath

I'm getting the following error while building FireBreath Solution file .

**The C Compiler Identification is unknown and
The CXX Compiler Identification is unknown**

Can any one help me figuring out where am I doing wrong.

Note: 1) I have VS professional installed with c++ compilers and libraries

Comment: i dont have that reputation to upload that...I will upload the error in about a minute

Comment: so you're saying it's actually an error when running the prep script? This is a cmake issue, not a firebreath issue.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it.  Some with similar issues have tried another computer or uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio

Comment: @taxilian: tried with both the alternatives suggested but efforts in vain.

Answer (score 1):

This may help

1. start visual-studio-2012 command prompt ([e.g. Win64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
2. run cmake command with appropriate generator ([e.g. -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64"](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#gen%3aVisualStudio12))

Answer (score 0):

My research indicates that this is most likely a broken visual studio installation.  You can try uninstalling / reinstalling, but if that doesn't work you might try making a new question that isn't tied to firebreath or plugins (which leads people to think they need to know something about firebreath or plugins to help you) and just asks about the error you're getting with cmake, since hte issue is actually that cmake isn't finding Visual Studio.

I have had this happen to me once before with VS2010 and to be honest I just ended up reinstalling the system.  There is a [thread about a similar issue](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-August/055517.html) where someone fixed it by copying an installation from another computer.

Other than that, I really have no idea.